# Apereo Cas - Custom Principal Id release

Tags: java, spring, cas

I need to edit the principal id that will be returned to a cas client application.

The principal I need to edit is returned from an external idp which I do not own and its format is like this:

```
Id: idp autogenerated ID having no meaning for my setup
Attributes:
... Some attributes I do not need ...
**ImportantId**(this is the property I need)
```

I have read the [official documentation](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/integration/Attribute-Release-PrincipalId.html) so from my understanding the related part of my service json file should be:

```
...       
"usernameAttributeProvider" : {
        "@class" : "com.mypackage.cas.principal.MyCustomRegisteredServiceUsernameProvider",
        "canonicalizationMode" : "NONE"
```

In my custom `UserNameProvider` class, I need to access db in order to get my setup specific username based on the **importantId** I mentioned above, so I need to do something like this :

```
public class MyCustomRegisteredServiceUsernameProvider implements RegisteredServiceUsernameAttributeProvider {

    @Autowired
    UsersService usersService;

    @Override
    public String resolveUsername(Principal principal, Service service, RegisteredService registeredService) {
        // String importantId = ...getting it from principal attributes.. 
        return usersService.getUserNameFromImportant(importantId);

    }   
}
```

The problem is that `Autowired` annotation unfortunately is not working, thus my `UsersService` is not initialized resulting in a NPE at runtime.

So, firstly I would like to know why my approach is not working and secondly what is the cas "official" way to achieve this behavior?

Cas Version: 5.3.4 Cas overlay template

Env: W10 x64, Java 8

Deployed on Wildfly 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, firstly I would like to know why my approach is not working

...because such providers are not spring-managed beans. They are serialized objects found off of JSON documents, and such and never pass through the Spring runtime.

> and secondly what is the cas "official" way to achieve this behavior?

One possible workaround would be to remove the injected field and do this in your `resolveUsername` method:

```
var appContext = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
var usersService = appContext.getBean("bean-name", UsersService.class);
return usersService.getUserNameFromImportant(importantId);
```